# Any way to access Google Drive Backup?

Tags: backup, google, restore, google-drive

I recently lost my phone and bought a new one. unfortunately I've bought one of those new Huawei phones that come without GMS. Now i still want to restore my google drive backup of my lost phone. I tried resetting an old phone with Android 3.X on it but it didn't give me any recovery options. Is there any way to either extract the google drive Backup or to recover the Data using an Android VM?

Answer (score 0):

one workaroud would be visiting drive.google.com from any browser on the huwaei phone

Or You can install F1 VM which comes with Google services framework.
BUt note that the restored backup would only run on the emulated Android - so you gotta keep this app forever .

https://f1vm.com/